# Bigquery Golang client get projects list

Tags: go, google-bigquery

How can I get a list of projects that the golang cloud client has access to using the serviceaccount key that I have provided?
Seems like there is an API available: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects/list

However, the Google Cloud client library does not expose it.

My code looks like this

```
client, err := bigquery.NewClient(ctx, conn.ProjectID, option.WithServiceAccountFile(fname))
```

I want to enumerate the list of projects that this client can access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

below example can give you an idea - it is sandboxed go that is part of our BQ UI

---

[image]

---

```
func mainReturn() interface{} {
    bigqueryService, err := getBigqueryService() ; if(err != nil) {return "ERROR"}
    err2 := getProjects(bigqueryService)         ; if(err2 != nil) {return "ERROR"}
    return "OK"
}

func getProjects(bigqueryService *bigquery.Service)(error) {
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    var pagetoken string = ""
    ind := 0
    for {
        call := bigqueryService.Projects.List()
        if len(pagetoken) > 0 {call = call.PageToken(pagetoken)}

        list, err := call.Do() ; if err != nil {return err}

        if len(pagetoken) == 0 {
            xFprintf(&buf, "TotalItems: %v\n", list.TotalItems)
        }

        for _, project := range list.Projects {
            xFprintf(&buf, "========= Projects %v ==============\n", ind)
            xFprintf(&buf, "Id: %v\n", project.Id)
            xFprintf(&buf, "Kind: %v\n", project.Kind)
            project := project.Id
            del := strings.LastIndex(project, ".")
            if del != -1 {project = project[del+1:]}
            ind++;
        }

        pagetoken = list.NextPageToken ; if len(pagetoken) == 0 {break}
    }

    xPrintln(buf.String())
    return nil
}
```

Please ignore some funny looking functions like xFprintf - this is just way we sandboxed go

Comment: It would be nice if you could give a sample of how to create the bigquery.service instance. I found it in the bigquery go client code anyways. Thanks!

Comment: as I mentioned - in above example - it is a sandboxed version of go with BQ client that we created for our UI and bigquery service is already precreated so our users do not need to worry of creating and authenticating etc. - just using :o)  glad you found how to actually create instance of bigquery.service on your own

Comment: @VishalJoshi could you share how you created the bigquery.service instance?